# Is there any way to identify unused asssets(images, files) in a flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was developing a flutter application. So I had to delete unused assets used in the project(mainly images) to reduce app size. How can we achieve this in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/app-size#:%7E:text=Reducing%20app%20size,-When%20building%20a&text=Some%20other%20things%20you%20can,Compress%20PNG%20and%20JPEG%20files) by the Flutter team for information on how to reduce app size.

Answer (score -1):

You can try delete unused packages and it would be good too for size app.
When you run `flutter build apk` or `flutter build apk --release`  app size very high when you try run this `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` app size will be reduced by architechture of processor. When you upload your project to store it will be required appbundle that why when you download app really from store it would show to reduced size app that's why dont worry.

Answer (score -1):

When you release app as appbundle it reduces by every [architechture](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#sa) that's why you do not need doing this proccess.It would we automatically changed when user download apk from google play

Comment: They are two different things. It is asking for a way to remove assets (images or files) added by the developer and no longer used (like an icon that is no longer used). What the playstore does in the case of the app bundle is to separate assets according to architecture or screen size